# Remove anchors from an iframe loaded with another protocol

Tags: jquery, iframe

I've being trying to remove the anchors of an iframe that I've loaded into my website, the problem I'm having is that jQuery doesn't allows me to do this as the iframe is being loaded using https and my website is http. Does anyone knows how to bypass this?

My current JS code is the following:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
     jQuery("#my-iframe").load(function () {
        jQuery('#my-iframe').contents().find('a').click(function() { return false; });
    });
});
```

The iframe is from a different domain

Comment: please share your relevant html code and script that you have tried so far.

Comment: JS has been added above. The HTML is just an iframe.

Answer (score 0):

If your website delivers HTTP pages, all active mixed content delivered via HTTPS on this pages will be blocked by default. You may need PHP or another server side language

Here's an example with PHP

get_https.php

```
die(file_get_contents('https://www.google.com.hk/'));
```

Your Page

```
<iframe id="my-iframe" src="get_https.php"></iframe>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
     jQuery("#my-iframe").load(function () {
        jQuery('#my-iframe').contents().find('a').click(function() { return false; });
    });
});
</script>
```